# Why My code don't show any output.That should show 'no match found'

Tags: python, for-loop

here is my code.This is simple Python code.This code isn't working.What should i do?Is there any better way to break a nested for loop.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b=[30,40,50,77,98,95]
i=0
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if(i==j):
              print("found a match")
              i+=1
              break
if(i==0):
    print("no match found")
```

Comment: Why would you expect `i` to be 0?  Your `for` loop set it equal to 9 at the end.

Comment: I realize the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will never be 0 because there is no 0 in a but it wouldn't matter because i is given the value of the last item in a (therefore the "no match found" wont print", other then that it seems good.
if you want to fix it then say X=0 and if(X==0): (use something other then i)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to figure out if there are any common elements in 2 lists.

Fixing your code with proper `for` loop :

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b=[30,40,50,77,98,95]
i=0
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        print("found a match")
        i+=1
        break
if i==0:
    print("no match found")
```

A more easier way to do this without for loop :

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b=[30,40,50,77,98,95]

common_elements = set(a).intersection(b)

if len(common_elements) != 0:
    print("Found a match")
else:
    print("No match found")
```

Te variable `common_elements` will have all the matching elements.

Comment: Let me know if above answer solves your problem  or incase you have any doubts/queries.